# Magento bitnami linux Setup Varnish

Tags: magento2, varnish, linux, speedoptimization

I want to configure and use : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish.html
for Magento in bitnami Linux

Can any one guide me port no which Port No Varnish should be deployed ??
I had deployed it on port 8080 and It caused some conflict in my server
Linux apache 2 bitnami

Please any one help!!

Comment: So what is the question? Specify your problem in the question

Comment: I want to know a easy guide

Comment: @Danila O have  Explaned the scnario now